# How to compute argmax with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I was wondering if there is any way to  get the parameter for which a given expression attains its maximum value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally get first the parameter and then evaluate to obtain the function value. For example:

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x', real=True) # parameter
f = -2 * x**2 + 4*x        # function
derivative = f.diff(x)     # -4*x + 4
solve(derivative, x)       # -4*x + 4 = 0
```

would get you `x=1`.